# Representations of finite p-groups G over a field K

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K$ be any field of characteristic $p > 0$ and let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Let $V$ be any $K$-linear
representation of $G$. Then prove that there exists a non-zero $v \in V$ such that $gv = v$ for all $g \in G$.

If $G$ is a finite group and $V$ is a vector space. Suppose $GL(V)$ denote the group of invertible $K-$linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. Then
I know that a linear representation of $G$ in $V$ is a homomorphism $p$ from the group $G$ into the group $GL(V)$.

Can anyone give me any hint for this problem. I am supposed to determine an element $v \in V$ such that it is doesn't change for any map $p_g \in GL(V)$ for any $g \in G$. That is $p_g(v)=v$ for all $g \in G$. Here $p_g \in GL(V)$.

How am I supposed to use the fact that $G$ is a of order $p^k$?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much simpler way but I think this solution is fun.

[Show](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/M250.01/center.html) that a finite $p$-group has a non-trivial center.

$$W=\bigcap_{z\in Z(G)} \ker(z-1)$$ $\quad$ (it is non-empty because they commute and $(z-1)^{p^k}=z^{p^k}-1=0\in K[G]$)

$W$ is a subrepresentation of $G$ (ie. $\forall g, gW\subset W$), since $Z(G)$ acts trivially it is also a representation of $G/Z(G)$.

Then replace $G,V$ by $G/Z(G),W$ and repeat until $G$ is trivial.

Any $v$ in the last $V$ will work.